# showing the hidden fragment onbackkey pressed in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

**What i am doing**::

- I am adding a fragment to a container on a Actionbar buttom press 
  also at the same time i am hiding the previous fragment
- Now on back-key pressed i want to just show the hidden fragment

**What is happening**::

- Instead of showing the previous fragment entire activity is removed
- How to overcome this
- I also tried with onBackpressed ... still the same result

**Code where this action taking place**::

```
}else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.searchID){
            /*Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SearchActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);*/

            ft1=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft1.hide(fragment1);
            ft1.add(R.id.content_frame, fragSearch);
            ft1.commit();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }    


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {
            ft1=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft1.show(fragment1);
            ft1.commit();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

{**Full Code**}

**MainActivity.java**

```
 public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements OnItemClickListener{

        private DrawerLayout drawlayout=null;
        private ListView listview=null;
        private ActionBarDrawerToggle actbardrawertoggle=null;

        FragmentTransaction ft1 ;
        FragSearch fragSearch=new FragSearch();
        mFragSortingHome fragment1=new mFragSortingHome();

        private String[] myfriendname=null;
        private int[] photo=null;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.drawer_activity_main);
            //Code moved to a seperate function from onCreate with a call in it for clarity
            drawerConfig(savedInstanceState);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
            actbardrawertoggle.syncState();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            actbardrawertoggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            if(item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home)
            {
                if(drawlayout.isDrawerOpen(listview))
                {
                    drawlayout.closeDrawer(listview);
                }
                else {
                    drawlayout.openDrawer(listview);
                }
            }else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.searchID){
                /*Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SearchActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);*/

                ft1=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft1.hide(fragment1);
                ft1.add(R.id.content_frame, fragSearch);
                ft1.commit();
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }    


        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
            {
                ft1=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft1.show(fragment1);
                ft1.commit();
            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
.             .            .      .
. . . . . other code . . .. . . . . .
.            .           .       .
```

{**EDIT**}

```
else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.searchID){
            /*Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SearchActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);*/

            ft1=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            //ft1.hide(fragment1);
            ft1.add(R.id.content_frame, fragSearch);
            ft1.addToBackStack(null);
            ft1.commit();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }    

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

---

I am able to ago back to previous fragment but again immidiately activity is also removed, i am not able to prevent the activity being removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FragmentManager backstack handles that sort of thing for you automatically. If you add

.addToBackStack(null);

to the transaction you're committing, pressing the back button will "undo" the last transaction on the stack. Instead of null, you can also use some string identifier if desired if you want to pop the backstack all the way back to a particular transaction.

No need to override onKeyDown. :)

Answer (score 1):

On back press try to pop the current fragment to show the previous fragment

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
            {
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
```

When adding a fragment you should also add it to backstack.. So put before  ft1.commit();

```
ft1.addToBackStack(null);
```

Comment: No need to handle onKeyDown, just add the addToBackStack call.

Comment: @kcoppock .... Hey your solution worked ..... i just added to backstack and removed onKeyDown function itself .... when i press back button my goal is achieved  ... if you post it as answer i will accept it  :)